MPU6050 - detect opposite of free fall - z-axis pull up detection
I'm struggling with getting a functionality similar to the free fall detection, but into the opposite direction - so to the top, f.e. if someone PULLING UP the sensor fastly.
I'm using an Arduino and a typical MPU6050 sensor, wired like this:

My code is looking like this:
#include "Wire.h"
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050.h"

MPU6050 mpu;
int16_t initial_ax, initial_ay, initial_az;
int16_t ax, ay, az;
int16_t gx, gy, gz;

struct MyData {
  byte X;
  byte Y;
  byte Z;
};

MyData initial_data;
MyData data;

const int THRESHOLD = 230;
bool enteredFirstTime = true;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  mpu.initialize();
  mpu.getMotion6(&initial_ax, &initial_ay, &initial_az, &gx, &gy, &gz);
  initial_data.Z = map(initial_az, -17000, 17000, 0, 255);       // Z axis data
}

void loop() {
  mpu.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);
  data.Z = map(az, -17000, 17000, 0, 255);       // Z axis data
  delay(500);
  Serial.println(data.Z);

  // if (data.Z < initial_data.Z * 0.5) {
  //     Serial.println("Triggered");
  // }
}


This is my serial monitor. it shows two sparks, one when I'm going upwads and stopping abruptly, but unfortunately the same when going downwards and stopping abruptly.


How are you exciting the sensor? If you yank it up quickly and then stop the movement equally quickly, you would make another quick acceleration in the downwards direction. Could it be that you're triggering on that?

I think you need to adjust your threshold. Free fall is when you have 0 g in Z axis. You want do detect when it is negative (depending on orientation of the mpu6050).

@MrGerber yes, i think this could be the actual reason for the peaks. I updated the code and added a plot from the serial monitor. maybe there is a solution to detect upwards movements?

@Rokta which one variable exactly I have to read and/or set?

I suspect 2Hz is a bit low sampling frequency for the test you're trying to do, also. I think it would be wise to take a few steps back and try to do a little bit of engineering. Analyse the situations you want to detect. Remember that objects move in 3D space with 6 degrees of rotation - think about an airplane. Apply some simple mechanics from high school physics and try to guesstimate the forces and directions for the sensor. That should make it easier for you to decide for yourself how to do this

@MrGerber with 2Hz you mean the baud rate or the delay(500)?

2Hz is the sampling frequency as a consequence of the 500ms delay.

@MrGerber ah, okay, again I learned something new^^ thanks.

Measuring motion with sampled-data systems is tricky, because accelerometers measure acceleration and not motion.
On earth, the acceleration of gravity (9.8 m/s^2) is always present and will be measured by every object that is either stationary or moving at a constant speed.  A freely falling object is a special case from an accelerometer standpoint.  When an object is falling it is accelerating at this rate, and the net measured acceleration is zero during the fall.  When stationary, the accelerometer reads 9.8 m/s^2, and during the entire fall, the accelerometers will read zero.  This is because the object is smoothly accelerating at this rate during the entire fall; it does not travel at a constant speed.
Now think of yourself on an elevator with your accelerometer.  When the elevator starts up, the elevator will accelerate from stopping to moving, and your accelerometer will measure this brief acceleration added to the acceleration of gravity.  Once the elevator is moving smoothly, both you and your accelerometer will not be able to feel anything different than you would feel if you were stationary.
So, the only way you can tell you have started moving up is by detecting the brief period of acceleration.  If you want to know how fast you are moving with some degree of accuracy, you must integrate a high-resolution, highly accurate acceleration signal during this brief period.  This will be imperfect in any sampled system.  If you want to know how far you have traveled, you would have to do the same measurement on the other end when the elevator decelerates to a stop.
Worse, as you have noticed, is the fact that positive acceleration in the upward direction happens in two instances:  when the object is stationary or moving upward at a constant speed and its speed increases, or when the object is moving downward and its speed decreases.  Both of these occurrences result in the accelerometer having a more positive value that the acceleration of gravity alone.  The converse is also true; in your example, the negative peak occurred not when the object was pulled upward but when you had finished pulling it up and decelerated to a stop.
I think your best hope might be to set a comparator threshold above the acceleration of gravity on the "Z" axis that would have to be exceeded after some baseline period where the acceleration was stable (no motion).  You  would know your application best.
Good Luck!

Thank you very much for this detailed explanation. The idea to use a comparator could be a good solution, i think.
